# Pair Sum - fixed sum, multiple subarrays

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

Given an array of numbers and a definite target sum `sum`, how to find, for one subarray after the other, the number of pairs which have their sum equal to `sum`?

I have tried using a hash-table and finding the number of occurrences of `sum-x` and `x`, `x` being an element of the subarray.

But how to optimise this for multiple queries (pairs of endpoints)?
Creating a hash table for each of the queries is too costly.

Comment: Does each query have a different target sum (x) or only a different subarray?

Comment: Is it possible for you to store the data in a sorted array? If so, I can probably offer an algorithm with an O(n) complexity per query, n being the size of the sub-array. Also what @גלעדברקן asked.

Comment: @BananaSenpai Isn't the original algorithm not already O(n)?

Comment: Touche, @SaiBot!! but he's using a hash table. I'm sorry i didn't point this out earlier, but my algorithm has the same complexity in an array, which is a much less space complex Data structure. Also, having a hash table wont help if you have a changing sub-array and sum specification, because hashing won't preserve the indexes, meaning, he'll have to create a new hash map for every query making his method as complex as O(n^2), because it requires generating a hashmap and then searching it.

Comment: @BananaSenpai uhm... for each query generating a hashmap is O(n) searching it n times is also O(n) which is O(n) in total, right?

Comment: Also, are all the queries given in advance?

Comment: The target sum is the same. But the subarry keeps changing. We get the values of the endpoints from the user. @גלעדברקן

Comment: @user10390214 what do you mean by end points? you mean 0 and arr.length-1, i.e. the start and end indices of the array?

Comment: I guess OP means the start and end points of the subarray-queries are user input. Which means they are not known beforehand.

Comment: @גלעדברקן "Also, are all the queries given in advance?" usually this is not done in practice or for any problem solving exercise too as far as I know. Queries shouldn't be considered when devising an algorithm. It will make the algorithm tuned to those specific queries only and any future queries will suffer.

Comment: You only need to record the values (`x`), you don't also need to record `sum-x`.

Comment: @SomeDude in every online platform that I've encountered that tests code submissions against a given task, all queries were always given (to the submitted program) in advance. That said, I agree with you that it may be useful to consider a more general approach.

Comment: Is your array sorted? If yes then we won't require any hash table as it won't be space efficient. If not then hashtable would be the only option to solve this problem in linear time.

Answer (score 1):

To start off the discussion, what about precomputing all results and then making them accessible efficiently?

Precomputing all index pairs `<i, j>` where `a[i] + a[j] = sum` can be performed offline in `O(n)` where `n` is the size of the input array `a`.

Afterwards you could store the precomputed pairs in a 2d spatial index structure (e.g., [R-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree#Search) or Quadtree).

A subarray query `(start, end)` corresponds then to a range query (with a quadratic box) on the 2d index with `min = (start, start)` and `max = (end, end)`.

Depending on the extent of the query this should be possible in O(log m) where m is the overall number of pairs.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for the hash table to be constructed for a specific sum: a hash table can be constructed in an initial step and queries for any `sum` can be answered in linear time for the full array.

For an array `arr` of length `n`, follow these steps:

- construct a hash table where you store the number of elements of `arr` that have the value `arr[i]`.
- for each `sum`: starting with a `total` of `0`

  - for each element of `arr` set `x = arr[i]`:

    - if `x * 2 < sum`, get the `count` of elements with value `sum - x`, add `count * 2` to `total`.
    - if `x * 2 == sum`, get the `count` of elements with value `x`, add `count + 1` to `total`
  - the number of pairs of elements of `arr` that add up to `sum` is `total / 2`

To answer queries for a subarray, the above approach does not work. You can of course always use nested loops and find the count in quadratic time with no extra space.

Here is a more efficient solution for subarrays and any given `sum`:

- initial step: construct an array of pairs `{ index: i, value: arr[i] }` and sort it by the `value` field: this initial step uses **O(n)** extra space and **O(n.log(n))** time.
- for any given pair of endpoints and a target sum: a linear scan from both ends of the sorted array, skipping the elements whose index is outside the endpoints, finds the count of pairs in linear time.

Here is an implementation for arrays of `int`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct array_values {
    size_t index;
    int value;
};

static int array_values_compare(const void *aa, const void *bb) {
    const struct array_values *a = aa;
    const struct array_values *b = bb;
    return (a->value > b->value) - (a->value < b->value);
}

struct array_values *sum_initialize(const int *arr, size_t n) {
    struct array_values *av = malloc(sizeof(*av) * n);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        av[i].index = i;
        av[i].value = arr[i];
    }
    qsort(av, n, sizeof(*av), array_values_compare);
    return av;
}

/* get the count of pairs whose sum is sum for subarray arr[start : end]
 * start index is included, end index is excluded.
 */
size_t sum_query(struct array_values *av, size_t n, size_t start, size_t end, int sum) {
    size_t i, j, count = 0;
    if (n > 0) {
        for (i = 0; j = n - 1; i < j; i++) {
            if (av[i].index >= start && av[i].index < end) {
                while (j > i && av[i].value + av[j].value > sum) {
                    j--;
                }
                while (j > i && av[i].value + av[j].value == sum) {
                    if (av[j].index >= start && av[j].index < end)
                        count++;
                    j--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: What about queries about *subarrays* specified by *endpoints*?

Comment: @greybeard: the hash table approach is fine for queries where `sum` varies. If the boundaries vary, I'm afraid the brute force quadratic scan is a good solution.  A more efficient one would be to construct an array of pairs [i, arr[i]] and sort it by values of arr[i]. A linear scan from both ends, skipping the elements which index is outside the endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm for finding the number of pairs of a given subarray which have their sum equal to a definite target sum:

1. Create a map to store frequency of each number in the array.
2. For every element check if it can be combined with any other element (other than itself!) to give the desired sum. Increment the counter accordingly.
3. Divide count by 2 and return.(why? because every pair is counted two times.)

Edit 1:
Here is my python solution. It can also be done using sets.

```
s=set()
result=set()
for item in a:
    target=original_target-i
    if target not in s:
       s.add(i)
    else:
        result.add((i,target))
print(len(result))
```

Note-sets are implemented as hash tables in python so unless the load factor is too high searching would take O(1) time. so the total complexity would be O(n)

Comment: step 2) of your algorithm unfortunately has O(n^2) runtime which is worse than the original idea  (having O(n)) mentioned in the question.

Comment: No the total complexity would still be O(n).Because we are using hash maps. so the searching for the element would take O(1)

Comment: you should add that crucial part to your answer. However, this is still no improvement over the original O(n), right?

Comment: yes, It would still take o(n) time, but I don't think we can solve this problem in less than O(n) time. I tried but couldn't solve it in less than O(n).

Comment: This does not answer `But how to optimise this for multiple queries?`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
vector<vector<int>>  pairSum(vector<int> &arr, int s){
    int n = arr.size();
    vector<vector<int>>pairs;
 for(int i=0; i<=n;i++)
 {
    for(int j=i+1;j<=n;j++)
    {
       if((arr[i]+arr[j]) == s)
       {
         vector<int> pair = {arr[i], arr[j]};
         pairs.push_back(pair);
       }
    }
 }
 return pairs;
}
```

Comment: Change `i <= n` to `i < n` and `j <= n` to `j < n`. Also translate this code to C and return the **number** of pars, not an array of pairs.  Finally, note that this algorithm uses brute force nested loops with a quadratic complexity, which the OP is trying to reduce to a linear complexity using a hash table.

Comment: This does not answer `But how to optimise this for multiple queries?`

Comment: You should *never* recommend `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` in  an answer on  Stack Overflow. Use the relevant **standard** headers, instead. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/10871073

Answer (score 0):

One memory-hungry approach:

Given an array `values` of length `n` and a target sum `sum`.
Establish the count of elements *smaller* than, *equal to*, and *greater* than `sum`/2 -
elements *equal to* may need to be handled specially if the number of *ordered* pairs is required.
For unordered pairs *of indexes*:
Assume *smaller* no greater than *greater*.
For each value `x` in `values` not exceeding `sum`/2, keep a data structure allowing to determine the count of occurrences of `x` in `values` in a given  range, e.g, an array of length `n` with the count before a given index.

For each query, iterate the values `x` of the subarray.
Accumulate the counts of `sum - x` for start point and end point; subtracting one if `x` equals `sum`/2 (this could be taken account of in precomputation).